# Quick question, how can I display my XSL code in a browser

Tags: xslt

I'm learning XSLT and, for testing purposes, would like be able to simply display my XSL code inside of a browser via a link from another page.  With the following anchor tag...

```
<a href="transform.xsl">My Test XSL Transform Code</a>
```

The code isn't displayed when the link is clicked, it's executed.  How can I display the code when I click that link?

Thanks in advance for all your help!

***UPDATE***

I found the solution, it was to add the following line at the top of my XSL stylesheet...

```
<xsl:output method="html" version="4.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" indent="yes"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rename it, or create a server side script that reads it and pushes it's textual form.

Answer (score 0):

Below is an XSL document that opens in IE when I serve it from LocalHost.  What does yours look like?  Are you referencing your target in it?